# passing data to different functions in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to figure out how i can pass a variable from one function to another in controller but, now i am getting null in the second function.
In this function i am able to get the variables very well from a view.

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{   
            $user = $request->user;
            $amount = $request->amount;
            $phone =  $request->phone;
            $make =  $request->make;
}
```

now I want to use `$request->phone` and make something like this in the second function :

```
public function passData(Request $request)
{   
             $phone =  $request->phone;//but from getData
             $make =  $request->make;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: how are you calling each function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call function from where you pass variable. Like if you want pass data from `getData` function you call `passData` function.

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{   
    $user = $request->user;
    $amount = $request->amount;
    $phone =  $request->phone;
    $make =  $request->make;

    $this->passData($request);
}
```

and received data in pass function.

```
public function passData($request)
{   
    $phone =  $request->phone;//but from getData
    $make =  $request->make;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is in a different controller, you have to import the controller and just use the variable phone by tappinh the Controller name and linked it with the phone variable. But if the phone var is in the same file, I guess you can just use the phone variable right away.

Comment: @Aimanlrfan02 it is in the same controller but when I call phone in the second function i get null